# Solve linear equations with minimum variance constraint from existing vector

Tags: python, optimization, mathematical-optimization, linear-programming, nonlinear-optimization

Suppose there are given matrices A (m x n), B(n x 1), and C(m x 1)

We want to solve for X such that A dot X = C with the constraint that we want X to have minimum variance from B, i.e. min((X-B)^2)

Are there any python packages that work well with this kind of problems? Also the matrix B is likely to be large, with thousands of entries.

Comment: Any QP solver will do. E.g. CVXOPT, CVXPY..

Answer (score 0):

Following **Erwin's** recommendation (in the comment), here is a solution using [cvxpy](http://www.cvxpy.org).

Keep in mind, that you got **two competing objectives**! This means, you either have to balance these (which one is how important) or post one of these as a fixed constraint (e.g. variance-diff lower than some given constant). Here is some code for the former.

Another remark: while your original variance-term is *sum-of-squares*, i'm using the *euclidean norm* here, which is better in regards to solving (nice [SOCP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Second-order_cone_programming) problem-formulation) and probably more interesting too in regards to balancing with *alpha*, as both grow the same (asymptotically).

The default-solver used is [ECOS](https://github.com/embotech/ecos) (open-source).

#### Code

```
import numpy as np
from cvxpy import *

""" Random data """
M = 10
N = 10
A = np.random.rand(M,N)
B = np.random.rand(N)
C = np.random.rand(M)

""" Solve """
alpha = 0.01                                             # Regularization 
factor -> multiple objectives

X = Variable(B.shape[0])
component_A, component_B = norm(A * X - C), norm(X - B)  # norm more useful than sum_of_squares
objective = Minimize(component_A + alpha * component_B)
problem = Problem(objective, [])                         # [] = no constraints
problem.solve(verbose=False)

print(problem.value)
print('A*X: ', A.dot(X.value).T.flatten())
print('C: ', C)
print('X: ', X.value.T.flatten())
print('B: ', B)
```

#### Output alpha=0.1 -> variance-diff not that important in comparison to A*X=C

```
0.02115062805819827
A*X:  [[ 0.08126681  0.61685533  0.51072777  0.62493694  0.33443435  0.70281179
   0.89593751  0.34521676  0.16157952  0.62992064]]
C:  [ 0.08126681  0.61685533  0.51072777  0.62493694  0.33443435  0.70281179
  0.89593751  0.34521676  0.16157952  0.62992064]
X:  [[-0.03327532 -0.32668216 -0.44441417  0.75708529 -0.00958777 -0.33155358
   0.60025503  0.52237198  0.3052468  -0.14709605]]
B:  [ 0.89801455  0.50875127  0.77806572  0.17184964  0.06610118  0.27861303
  0.40513181  0.85778655  0.86835541  0.32786036]
```

#### Output alpha=10 -> variance more important compared to A*X=C

```
5.3146149509187195
A*X:  [[ 1.87714559  2.11056115  1.74268386  1.68503155  2.59590194  
1.9540973 2.37874233  2.07600857  1.6713983   1.2590621 ]]
C:  [ 0.18125564  0.33469345  0.63367096  0.0075308   0.19983206  0.76975212
  0.22084296  0.35758024  0.0214036   0.42501635]
X:  [[ 0.25227884  0.4022509   0.17074389  0.22068181  0.04595178 0.85354537
   0.1039422   0.76882144  0.85936741  0.14723398]]
B:  [ 0.25227884  0.4022509   0.17074389  0.22068181  0.04595178  0.85354537
  0.1039422   0.76882144  0.85936741  0.14723398]
```

A random **dense 1000x1000** problem took 15 secs on my machine using ECOS (commercial solver MOSEK will do it in ~ 1 sec). One could also use solver [SCS](https://github.com/cvxgrp/scs), which can be much faster with slightly reduced precision (and can run on GPU in one of two configurations -> indirect-mode).

Both solvers can gain a lot if your problem would be **sparse**.